# Change in vagrant requires removal of saved state in VirtualBox

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am running `Vagrant 2.2.2` on a MacBook Pro, with `VirtualBox`, Version 6.0.4 r128413.  A Mac update cascaded a need to update these about 2 months ago.

When I enter `vagrant status` it says "saved".  If I run `vagrant up` the following results:

```
My-MBP:vbox4 oliverwilliams$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Resuming suspended VM...
==> default: Booting VM...
    There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
    for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

    Command: ["startvm", "894fe7ac-8c87-4c18-8afa-4b24b6268f19", "--type", "headless"]

    Stderr: VBoxManage: error: Failed to load unit 'lsilogicscsi' (VERR_SSM_LOADED_TOO_LITTLE)
    VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole
```

I can "Discard Saved State" and then do `vagrant up` and it works but that's a pain.  I opened the VirtualBox UI, went to Machine > Settings, and under storage (after I discarded saved state but not before), I see Controller:SCSI - no option to change to SATA:AHCI as this post suggests: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/18263.

How do I fix this so a saved state can be stored without having to discard it?